# TTSPlaybackCreate unable to initialize dynamics: -3000 Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, text-to-speech

My Obj-C application using text to speech start to get ***[TTS] TTSPlaybackCreate unable to initialize dynamics: -3000*** error I have no idea why is that happening means I checked internet and application code if there was an answer to this problem but could not find any.

Seems to be a new iOS version bug but it is been a long time that this error started and there is no solution yet.

A development has been since I asked that question. I am still unable finding  the reason why I am having this message but I am able to make it speak now. ***utterance.preUtteranceDelay*** was ***0.1***

```
  utterance.preUtteranceDelay = 0.1;
```

When I remove that setting or make the value 0.

```
  utterance.preUtteranceDelay = 0;

 [synth speakUtterance:utterance];
```

Makes the speech.

Comment: it should be not new iOS version bug, as i am using tts already.Its working fine. Not sure about your error.

Comment: It is known bug from Apple, https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87691

Comment: Yes I know it is known but there is no answer in Apple Forum either so I can not progress.